# How to use external database in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-database

I want use **`External database`** in my application. in my application has 4 `fragment`, and show any fragments one of tables in database (database has 4 tables). but when start run the application, show me this error :

```
03-06 16:59:46.350 9654-9654/com.tellfa.dastanak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.tellfa.dastanak, PID: 9654
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.tellfa.dastanak.Database.DataBase.getCat1_Datas2(DataBase.java:156)
                                                                   at com.tellfa.dastanak.Fragments.Home_Frag.refreshData(Home_Frag.java:58)
                                                                   at com.tellfa.dastanak.Fragments.Home_Frag.onCreateView(Home_Frag.java:49)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Met
```

**Database codes:**

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME = "Dastansara";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }

        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database alerdy exist
        } else {

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            /// database does't exist yet
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Open DataBase
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    /**
     * Close DataBase
     */
    public void closeDataBase() {

        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public Cursor getCat1_Datas2() {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = 1";
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**DataProvider codes:**

```
public class DataProvider {

    int _id, _catID, _fav;
    String _title, _description;
    byte[] _image;

    public DataProvider(int key_id, int key_catID, int key_fav, String key_title, String key_description, byte[] key_image) {
        this._id = key_id;
        this._catID = key_catID;
        this._fav = key_fav;
        this._title = key_title;
        this._description = key_description;
        this._image = key_image;
    }

    /// Empty Constructor
    public DataProvider(){

    }

    public DataProvider(int key_id, String key_title){
        this._id = key_id;
        this._title = key_title;
    }

    public byte[] getKey_image() {
        return _image;
    }

    public void setKey_image(byte[] key_image) {
        _image = key_image;
    }

    public String getKey_description() {
        return _description;
    }

    public void setKey_description(String key_description) {
        _description = key_description;
    }

    public String getKey_title() {
        return _title;
    }

    public void setKey_title(String key_title) {
        _title = key_title;
    }

    public int getKey_fav() {
        return _fav;
    }

    public void setKey_fav(int key_fav) {
        _fav = key_fav;
    }

    public int getKey_catID() {
        return _catID;
    }

    public void setKey_catID(int key_catID) {
        _catID = key_catID;
    }

    public int getKey_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setKey_id(int key_id) {
        _id = key_id;
    }

}
```

**Fragment codes:**

```
public class Home_Frag  extends Fragment {

    DataProvider dataProvider;
    DataBase dataBase;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    Cat1_frag_adapter cat1FragAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home,
                container, false);

        refreshData();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void refreshData(){

        dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
        sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dataBase.getCat1_Datas2();

        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        cat1FragAdapter = new Cat1_frag_adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_card_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(cat1FragAdapter);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                int id, catID, fav;
                String title, desvription;
                byte[] image;
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                title = cursor.getString(2);

                dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, title);
                cat1FragAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem? tnx all <3

Comment: what do you mean external database? external databases are considered to be the ones that run standalone and not within the android application. External Database are databases like : mysql, mongoDB, etc. SQLite is internal database.

Comment: @helldawg13, I create database with SQLite Expert application and fill it many data and copy this database in my application. my database is Sqlite. I really need this help please help me if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problemm is here:

```
public Cursor getCat1_Datas2() {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = 1";
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

It is giving a `NullPointerException` because as stated in here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

> sql   String: the SQL query. The SQL string must not be terminated
>
> selectionArgs  String: You may include ? s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

So what you have to do is change your code to this:

```
public Cursor getCat1_Datas2() {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";
            
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"1"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

In your `onCreateView` method in your `Fragment` you are having this:

```
dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = dataBase.getCat1_Datas2();
```

Modify your method like this:

```
public Cursor getCat1_Datas2(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    
            try {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";
                
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"1"});
    
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                return cursor;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

then in your `OnCreateView()` try this:

```
dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
    sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.getCat1_Datas2(sqLiteDatabase);
```

Modify your `refreshData()` method to this:

```
public void refreshData(View view){

        dataBase = new DataBase(getActivity());
        sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dataBase.getCat1_Datas2();

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        cat1FragAdapter = new Cat1_frag_adapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_card_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(cat1FragAdapter);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                int id, catID, fav;
                String title, desvription;
                byte[] image;
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                title = cursor.getString(2);

                dataProvider = new DataProvider(id, title);
                cat1FragAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

and then call it like this:

```
refreshData(rootView);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks man, but show me again error in this line : `Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"1"});`

Comment: again `NullPointerException`?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
                                                                         at .Database.DataBase.getCat1_Datas2(DataBase.java:157)
                                                                         at .Fragments.Home_Frag.refreshData(Home_Frag.java:50)
                                                                         at.Fragments.Home_Frag.onCreateView(Home_Frag.java:41)`

Comment: @helldawg13 please help me :(

Comment: @spongeBob, please help me :(

Comment: @helldawg13, thanks man, you are great man <3 . this error is fix but show me error again in listview adapter : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.tellfa.dastanak.Fragments.Home_Frag.onCreateView(Home_Frag.java:47)` can you help me for this error? please :(